# Unique semaphore for each thread

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I have been assigned a modified version of the "Santa Claus" semaphore problem.
**Santa Claus** is a thread that randomly wakes up to check how many and what kind of threads are waiting to report to him (**Work elves** and **Collecting elves**)

What I have made are **work elf** and **collecting elf** threads:

```
void *collectingElf(void *arg, int semaphoreIndex) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&elveCountMutex);                          //semaphore for critical section, the number of elves
        printf("\nCollecting! %d\n", (int) pthread_self()); // thread is collecting stuff
        sleep((unsigned int) (rand() % 4));                           // thread sleeps for a random amount of time

        printf("Done collecting! %d\n", (int) pthread_self());    // Print process ID, just for easier tracking
        sem_post(&elveCountMutex);                            // Release the elve count semaphore
        sem_wait(&collectingElveSem);

    }
}

void *workingElf(void *arg)                             //same as collecting elf
{
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&elveCountMutex);
        printf("\nWorking! %d\n", pthread_self());
        sleep(1);
        workingElveCount++;
        printf("Done working! %d\n", pthread_self());
        sem_wait(&workElfSem);
        sem_post(&elveCountMutex);
    }
}
```

So here the elve counts are protected, since the threads can only access the counters when **elveCountMutex** is locked. This I can understand and this seems logical. Afterwards the thread should block and wait for **Santa** to unblock it. 
So, from what I read, once semaphore reaches value 0, thread will block. Anything above 0 will not block it, and negative value indicates how many threads are waiting for the semaphore to be unlocked.

So, once the threads running are finished, they decrement the semaphore, and block.

However, what I cannot seem to grasp is this part of the assignment:

For a collecting meeting to start, at least one **work elf** and three **collecting elves** are necessary. • If enough elves are present that both meetings could start, the collecting-meeting
always has priority, and **all work-elves not needed anymore resume their work**.

Say if I have 3 work elves, and I need only 1, how do I release the remaining 2 threads? Do I need a separate semaphore for each thread? Or am I missing something?

Edit: My bad, I completely forgot to tell about the **Santa** implementation.
**Santa** wakes up and releases the semaphores, in this way:

```
void* Santa(void *arg)
{
   while (1) {
      sleep((unsigned)rand() % 4);                                  //Santa sleeps randomly between 0 and 3 seconds;
      sem_wait(&elveCountMutex);                                      //access both elf counters
      if(workingElveCount>=2 && collectingElveCount >= 3)            //decide which meeting should commence
      {
         int releaseWorkElveCount = workingElveCount-1;
         for(int i = 0;i<releaseWorkElveCount;i++)
         {
            sem_post(&workElfSem);
         }
         sleep(5);
         collectingMeeting(&collectingMeetingThread);                //This just prints that we are in a collecting meeting 
         pthread_join(collectingMeetingThread,0);
         sem_wait(&elveCountMutex);
         for(int i=0;i<workingElveCount;i++)
         {
             sem_post(&workElfSem);
         }
         for(int i=0;i<collectingElveCount;i++)
         {
             sem_post(&collectingElveSem);
         }
         workingElveCount=0;
         collectingElveCount=0;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your management of semaphore

In

```
void *collectingElf(void *arg, int semaphoreIndex) {
    while (1) {
        ...
        sem_wait(&collectingElveSem);
    }
}
```

that gets but never releases `collectingElveSem`, and that in an infinite loop ?

In

```
void *workingElf(void *arg)                             //same as collecting elf
{
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&elveCountMutex);
        ...
        sem_wait(&workElfSem);
    }
}
```

that get but never release `elveCountMutex` and `workElfSem`, and that in an infinite loop. `collectingElf` also (try to) get `elveCountMutex` but I will not able to do after one turn in `workingElf`

If your semaphore are not recursive `workingElf` will also be blocked after one turn because not able to get again the semaphores. If the semaphore are recursive this cannot be for an infinite deep and `workingElf` will block itself after enough loops

Comment: You are right, my bad. Santa should release them. But how do I release 2 out of 3?

Comment: @Atizs ah sure that change the bahavior ;-) Can you add the rest of code ? How much _collectingElf_ threads there are ? Why the second parameter in `void *collectingElf(void *arg, int semaphoreIndex)` ? How much elves, 9 ?

Comment: @Atizs where _collectingElveCount_ is modified ? I think you need to post all your code ... (and me to sleep)